# Regex detect a sub-string from a string, and replace with white space

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

Need to detect all the instances of a sub-string of the form "`Índice - n -`" from a string and replace them with a white space.

Also, "n" can be any positive number and there can be 1 or more spaces before and after the string, and in between words.

I think I can use this function:

```
$myString = preg_replace( '/\sÍndice\s+/', ' ', $myString );
```

But I am stuck in the regex expression.

For example:

"`This is a sentence Índice - 8 -    forever`"
would become
"`This is a sentence forever`"

"`Just do it. Índice - 3 -`"
would become
"`Just do it.` "

Please help.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Kb99hO/7 - Does this work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex:

**Code:**

```
$arr = [
    "This is a sentence Índice - 8 -    forever",
    "Just do it. Índice - 3 -",
];
foreach ($arr as $str) {
    echo preg_replace('/\h*Índice - \d+ -\h*/', ' ', $str), "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
This is a sentence forever
Just do it.
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/ePL7FF/1)

Comment: This worked perfectly! It caught all the instances. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Toto - I have a question to ask. Shall I invite you to a chat for few mins ?

Comment: @rootkonda: Which question?

Comment: It is irrelevant to this post. hence I dont want to continue here.  As you are an experienced SO user, I believe you are the right person I can talk to. If you don't wish to give me even few mins. Please let me know who can I talk to about general SO question?

Comment: @rootkonda: If it's a general question about SO, there is a [dedicated site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).  If it's a specific question  I'll be glad to answer if I can.

Comment: @Toto - From Morning, you are in the context. So I think you can help. Here is the link - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219816/room-for-rootkonda-and-toto